# Send data over server from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, gsm, datalogger, simcom

How large chunk data of data is send over internet using GSM module or ESP from some kind of microcontroller.
As they both have a limit of data sent by TCP so how is it done and what is used to achieve the same?
Continous multiple requests will be time taking isn't it?

Comment: They probably use "packets". Try googling data packets.

Comment: TCP is optimized for sending a series of full packets, so much so that it's classically a bit slow about actually sending just one small one.